# What is necessary to backup the schema?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

The [Datastax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_snapshot_restore_t.html) states

> Cassandra can only restore data from a snapshot when the table schema exists. If you have not backed up the schema, [...]

What is required for a full backup of the schema? Simply backing up the `system` keyspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to backup the system keyspaces, they will be recreated when DSE is installed on the new node. However, you'll need the schema for any user-defined keyspaces.

To backup the schema:

```
$ cqlsh -e "DESCRIBE SCHEMA;" > schema.out
```

To restore on a new node:

```
$ cqlsh < schema.out
```

Answer (score 2):

In cqlsh (included with Cassandra), use the `DESC SCHEMA` command.

```
    DESCRIBE [FULL] SCHEMA

      Output CQL commands that could be used to recreate the entire (non-system) schema.
      Works as though "DESCRIBE KEYSPACE k" was invoked for each non-system keyspace
      k. Use DESCRIBE FULL SCHEMA to include the system keyspaces.
```